# Migrate Digital Ocean namespace to Openshift cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, digital-ocean

we're using digital ocean and redhat openshift. Now, we want to migrate namespaces from DO to Openshift for various reasons, but I am unable to find any resources online describing the process of migrating data from Digital Ocean to Openshift. Could anyone please explain the needed steps? Thanks!